# JUnit @Ignore all other tests (@IgnoreOther ?)

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jboss-arquillian

I'm testing extensively with JUnit and sometimes - while debugging my code - I want (temporary) only run a single `@Test` of my `@RunWith(Arquillian.class)` test class. Currently I'm adding a `@Ignore` to all other tests and wondering if something like `@IgnoreOther` does exist.

Are there better solutions to ignore all other tests?

Comment: This one speaks about runtime ignoring http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2008/10/run-time-equivalent-to-junits-ignore.html

Comment: Does your IDE not allow you to simply highlight the test you're interested in and only run that?

Comment: I don't know of an annotation like that, but I do the same thing quite a bit.  Maybe a good idea for a feature request?

Comment: @Duncan: I often execute Arquillian tests from the console.

Comment: @Jakrabbit: The tracker for junit hosted in Sourceforge is only visible for group members. I'm not sure where to post such a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Test rules](http://cwd.dhemery.com/2010/12/junit-rules/) (JUnit 4.7+) will help. For example, you can write a rule that [ignores all @Test methods except one with a specific name](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2010/10/running-a-single-junit-test).

Comment: Don't link to content that may (and has already) disappear. Copy the relevant part in your answer instead.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is to replace all `@Test` to `//###$$$@Test`. Then when your debugging is finished replace `//###$$$@Test` to `@Test`.

Moreover typically IDEs allow running one test only. For example in Eclipse you can do it from Outline view.

Answer (score 10):

Just my two cents. You can try to use [Junit Rules](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/package-summary.html) as @srkavin suggested.

Here is an example.

```
package org.foo.bar;

import org.junit.rules.MethodRule;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class SingleTestRule implements MethodRule {
    private String applyMethod;
    public SingleTestRule(String applyMethod) {
        this.applyMethod = applyMethod;
    }
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod method, final Object target) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                if (applyMethod.equals(method.getName())) {
                    statement.evaluate();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.foo.bar;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IgnoreAllTest {

    @Rule
    public SingleTestRule test = new SingleTestRule("test1");

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        Assert.fail("test2");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        Assert.fail("test3");
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Should be using TestRule with 4.9 and later versions though.

Comment: Agree. Too lazy to replace eclipse built-in 4.8 version.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from [srkavin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316379) (and [mijer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316959)) is correct, but the code is deprecated from JUnit 4.9. The interface and the method signature have changed. I want to provide this for others interested in this issue.

```
public class IgnoreOtherRule implements TestRule
{
  private String applyMethod;

  public IgnoreOtherRule(String applyMethod){
    this.applyMethod = applyMethod;
  }

  @Override
  public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final Description description)
  {
    return new Statement()
    {
        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            if (applyMethod.equals(description.getMethodName())) {
                statement.evaluate();
            }
        }
    };
  }
}
```